# User Authorization on page level

Tags: silverlight, authentication

Well I know a little about how to use user authentication Silverlight but now I want to know how I can implement authentication over page level. I mean how can I prevent unauthenticated users from accessing a page?

Comment: Do you mean authentication (confirming the identity of a user) or authorization (confirming the authenticated user has sufficient privileges?)

Comment: Its Authorization. I want to restrict the user to acces the page on its role basis.

Comment: Then please edit your question accordingly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a custom [ContentLoader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.contentloader%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that is used by the Navigation.Frame.

The ContentLoader could keep track of the user's identity (and roles) and decide what content is available.

[See this article for an example](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Authorization-in-Silverlight-part-1-Authorized-navigation.aspx)